# Apache HTTP Client 4.2.5 NTLM Integrated Authentication

Tags: java, apache, http, authentication, ntlm

Can anyone explain to me how (if it's possible) to setup integrated NTLM authentication when calling some URI via the Apache HTTP Client in Java?  I have successfully used it when supplying the NTCredentials, but I also need the ability to call additional web resources with whatever user the Java application is running as.  This works fine for HTTPUrlConnection (it automatically negotiates as the running user), but I haven't found a way to make it work with the Apache HTTP Client.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CloseableHttpClient httpclient = WinHttpClients.createDefault();` from the httpcomponents library 4.5